# get sequence of number in a list

Tags: python, sequence

I have a list `[3,6,9,15,24,27,30,33]`. What I'm trying to do is get a sequence of number that is multiple of 3 and equal or more than 3 items. If we based on the list the program should get `[3,6,9] [24,27,30,33]` is this possible?

Comment: you need the two lists separated?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: "is this possible?" Yes -- Python is Turing complete.

Comment: I still don't understand what the OP wants.

Comment: And yet this has 1 upvote...

Comment: I'm still puzzled why 15 is not included in the result set, and some other particulars of this question as well. Then, there's no accepted answer, and no comments on the answers by the asker suggesting this is of no interest. So, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

From what i have understood, you want the ***sublists having consecutive multiples of 3***  *( the reason you omitted 15 form your result )* ***with size of the sublists being greater than or equal to 3.***

While the answer by [FMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55857/fmc) is correct, it'll consider `15` where answer should be `[3, 6, 9]` and `[24, 27, 30, 33]`.

So just expanding on his answer:

```
def multiples_of_min_length(xs, factor, min_len):
    ys = []
    for x in xs:
        if x % factor == 0 and len(ys) == 0:
            ys.append(x)
        elif x % factor == 0 and (x - ys[-1] == 3):
            ys.append(x)
        else:
            if len(ys) >= min_len:
                yield ys
            ys = []
    if len(ys) >= min_len:
        yield ys
```

`xs = [3,6,9, 15,17,19,  24,27,30,33,  39,47,  54,57,60]`

```
fin_sublists = []
for ys in multiples_of_min_length(xs, 3, 3):
    fin_sublists.append(ys)

fin_sublists
```

**OUTPUT**

`[[3, 6, 9], [24, 27, 30, 33], [54, 57, 60]]`

Comment: Your description of my answer is incorrect.

Comment: I suppose providing the list `[3,6,9,15,24,27,30,33]` in your answer will give the `whole list` as output instead of `[3,6,9]` and `[24,27,30,33]` as mentioned in the question, otherwise using generators is indeed a great way to solve this. But anyway, It would be great if you could tell me if i'm misunderstanding something. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh -- point taken. You are correct after all. +1  :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking for multiples of three in this example is a bit pointless, because it will return every item in your list, since each is a multiple of three. However you can check using [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
list_to_check = [3,6,9,15,24,27,30,33]
multiples = filter(lambda x: x%3==0, list_to_check)
```

The second part of your question doesn't make sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [3,6,9,15,24,27,30,33]

new_list = []

list_of_lists = []

for item in my_list:
    if item % 3 == 0:
        if (len(new_list) == 0):
            new_list.append(item)
        else:
            if (item - new_list[-1]) == 3:
                new_list.append(item)
            else:
                if len(new_list) > 2:
                     list_of_lists.append(new_list)
                new_list = []
                new_list.append(item)

if len(new_list) > 2:
    list_of_lists.append(new_list)



print list_of_lists # or print(list_of_lists) for Python 3.x
```